# Global inflation-linked private debt data

Tags: data-request, economics, global

There are many available studies on total global debt figures; both private and public amounts.

Specifying the question to *inflation-linked* (in some contexts referred to as [inflation-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation-indexed_bond)) debt significantly cuts down the results. There are a couple [Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-world-tied-3-5-trillion-plus-of-debt-to-inflation-the-costs-are-now-adding-up-b8db69d5) articles about global public inflation-linked debt (supposedly according to the Bank for International Settlements, but I'm having trouble finding that study, and I can't access the WSJ article to use the citation).

For global *private* inflation-linked debt, I am unable to find anything substantial - are there any good data sources for this?